# Oracle Database connection via SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to connect to my Oracle database from SQLPlus, but I'm not able to connect.

I have Oracle client(10g) on my machine. Below are the details through which I am able to connect from my Java application.

```
connect('dbi:Oracle://IP/wborcle', 'username', 'pwd'));
```

What will be the hoststring when connecting via SQLPLUS?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: ORA : 12154 TNS : could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're using Java? DBI is a Perl library for connecting to Oracle.

Answer (score 19):

Try

```
sqlplus username/password@host:port/service

sqlplus system/system@localhost:1521/xe
```

Copied from 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65032/connect-to-sql-plus-from-command-line-using-connection-string

Comment: This method fails to connect to an Oracle database link

Answer (score 8):

Oracle offers several different methods for lookup up databases when you're trying to connect to them:

- tnsnames.ora entries
- LDAP
- EZConnect
- ...

The most common approach is to put the databases you're connecting to into your `tnsnames.ora`; usually, your client installation contains an example tnsnames.ora file that you can modify.

The easiest approach is probably to use EZConnect. An EZConnect string is built like

`<username>/<password>@<hostname>:<port>/SID`

so in your case, it (probably) will be something like

`sqlplus scott/tiger@localhost:1521/wborcle`

Answer (score 4):

```
 sqlplus user/pass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=hostname.network)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=remote_SID)))
```

Maybe, and this might be dependant on the command line environment you're using, you need to quote the string, something like

```
sqlplus "user/pass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=hostname.network)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=remote_SID)))"
```

or

```
 sqlplus 'user/pass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=hostname.network)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=remote_SID)))'
```

Comment: Hi Mariano, can you please explain this more. i m not able to understand this.

Comment: _"Are you 100% sure you're using Java? DBI is a Perl library for connecting to Oracle."_

Answer (score 2):

```
sqlplus username/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=hostname)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sidname)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If using the standard client, in order to use ezconnect syntax  you may have to  set it in your sqlnet.ora file, in the network/admin directory of the client

names.directory_path=(tnsnames,ezconnect)